# How do you add CORS headers in Redstone interceptor?

Tags: dart, redstone.dart

I'm trying to add CORS headers to incoming requests but I've noticed that `app.response.headers` is an immutable map and `app.request.response` doesn't exist even though it appears in the documentation examples. So, to the `OPTIONS` request I'm replying using a new `Shelf` response, but I can't find a way to add any new headers to the response of the actual request. Any ideas?

```dart
@app.Interceptor(r"/api/.*", chainIdx: 1)
corsInterceptor() {

    if (app.request.method == "OPTIONS") {
        var response = new shelf.Response.ok("", headers: HEADERS);
        app.chain.interrupt(statusCode: HttpStatus.OK, responseValue: response);
    } else {
    // app.request.response is not available
        app.request.response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        app.chain.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix in the first piece of code inside the Interceptor documentation...:)

```dart
@app.Interceptor(r"/api/.*", chainIdx: 1)
corsInterceptor() {
    if (app.request.method == "OPTIONS") {
        var response = new shelf.Response.ok("", headers: HEADERS);
        app.chain.interrupt(statusCode: HttpStatus.OK, responseValue: response);
    } else {
        app.chain.next(() => app.response.change(headers: HEADERS));
    }
}
```

`app.chain.next()` can take a callback as argument, which is expected to return a `Response` object. In this case `app.response.change()` returns a response with the correct headers.