# In dart httpRequest getstring always error

Tags: dart, httprequest

I established a RESTful server, and I can get a simple string with my Chrome or IE using this URL: "http://localhost:8080/WebService/RESTful/getString"

But when using Dart, it always returns a error message:

```
"[object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent]"
```

From the `onError()` callback method,
I'm sure that server returns a string with "text/plain" MIME type in Java.

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
    HtmlElement btn = document.body.querySelector("#btn");
    btn.onClick.listen(onClick);
}

void onClick(Event v) {
  var url = "http://localhost:8080/WebService/RESTful/getString";
  HttpRequest.getString(url).then((str) {
    window.alert(str.toString());
  }, onError: (e) {
  window.alert(e);
 });
}
```

Who can help me ?

Comment: You're alerting the `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` which contains the actual error. Inspect `e` in your browser's debugger to see the real problem.

Comment: how to inspect e in my browser's ? sorry ,I'm a beginner in dart .

Comment: Most browsers have a debug console - Firefox (Ctrl-Shift-S), IE (F12), Chrome (Ctrl-Shift-I). You can then place a breakpoint inside your `onError` function and inspect all variables which are in scope.

Comment: Thanks ,I get the Error information XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/WebService/RESTful/getString. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to fetch resources from another server than the one your page was loaded from, this server needs to return CORS headers otherwise your browser refuses to fetch form this other server. 
It depends on your server how this can be configured or added.

See for example
- [How do you add CORS headers in Redstone interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749814)
- [CORS with Dart, how do I get it to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456591)